# If div has a line-height of 0 and its only child, span, has line-height:0, where's the div's height coming from?

Tags: css

Here's my doubt. I've got a parent div with a child which is a span. Both have line-height set to 0. The span has font-size set to many many pixels (198px).

The problem: the div gets a height. But, from what, if it should come from the spans line-height, which is 0?

I set up a tinkerbin. Check it out if if you're interested.

http://tinkerbin.com/0oCT7PRf

This happens at least in firefox and chrome, so this is almost definitely a standardized behavior.

Note!
This is a css behavior doubt. I'm interested in knowing what's happening, not on "fixing" an "issue".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The text still has a size; the letter 'F' is expanding the `div` to fit.

**Update** from the spec:

> On a **block container** element whose content is composed of **inline-level elements**, 'line-height' specifies the *minimal* height of line boxes within the element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height

So the height of the box really is coming from the font-size, as the line-height is only defined as a *minimum* of 0, but not explicitly 0.

Comment: The text is inside a "line box". That line box's height comes from the line height property. I set it to 0 in this case. I also set a line height on the parent block level container to 0. That sets the minimal line height of the line boxes inside it to 0 - so, the answer which could have come from here, can't anymore. The parent block level container should be 0 and it isn't. Set the vertical align to top on the span and you "get" what I believe is the commonly expected result. I fiddled with this a little bit since yesterday and I believe I'm coming to understand the behavior.Ill post t later

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/ynZ4KrTk --> inspect the .box element with your browser. See that now that the font-size is set to 14px the .box-element has a computed height of 0. Whys is that that when it's 14px the parent box sees no height? and when it's greater it sees a height?

Comment: seems like an issue with the way computed heights are displayed in the inspector, because the `span` has a height of 8px (auto).

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/Dilt3PPx - Why it works: according to the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading), the line box height isn't taken directly from the line-height property for calculation, instead it is derived from the formula in section 10.8.1. You change the resultant height by zeroing out the factors via `vertical-align`. That said, it explicitly states that there is still room for UA interpretation in other rendering calculations to throw off the whole appearance...

Comment: Yeah. I guess you're right. This is what bugs me though... the spec says somewhere "The height of the inline box encloses all glyphs and their half-leading on each side and is thus exactly 'line-height'". So if line-height=0, height of inline-box = 0; And it doesnt quite look like that here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the  is taking the height of its inner element. If you want it to correctly take its defined height/line height, you have to set it to behave as a block element ( display:block;)

Also, when hiding elements on IE using line height / height :0, IE won't collapse the element unless font-size is set to 0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've comeup with:

First facts backed by the spec:

When you have a line height greater than the font-size - what you usually see - it's pretty easy. Take the line height, subtract the font-size, divide it by 2. Apply the result to both the top and the bottom of the "glyphs box", and that's it. So if your font-size is 14px, and your line height 16px:

16px - 14px = 2px
2px / 2 = 1px

Add 1px above the "glyphs box", add 1px below it. The box gets a height of 16px, and that as expected becomes the height of the parent container (assuming, as in the case, that there's only one line-box in it).

When the line-height is less than the font-size (our case) the thing gets trickier. Lets use the same formula for a font-size of 54px and a line-height of 0.

0-154px = -154px (the spec allows a negative value here so we're alright)

-154px / 2 = -77px

So, our font has a size of 154px... and here's something else you need to know. A font has both a distance from the baseline to it's top and from the baseline to it's bottom. Pretty simple. The spec calls the first one height(A) and the second one depth(D). So A+D = distance from top to bottom.

Now here's what I think is happening in the case I presented in the question. This is what I concluded from "my fiddling" and not from the spec (since I couldn't find it there).

Let's continue with our formula.

We got -77px from dividing the result of the difference between the line-height and the font-size.

Our font-size is 154px.

Now we've got to add -77px to the top, and -77px to the bottom. Adding a negative is subtracting - so we're in fact subtracting 77px.

This is easier explained with a drawing.

[image]

So yeah, that's where I believe the height is coming from. It's at least related to it.